# How can the iOS pip window be successfully implemented

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, avplayer, avkit

I wrote a method using Flutter MethodChannel to call iOS pip to play videos. It can be played, but the pip window does not appear proactively. When I manually put the app in the background, the pip window appears. So I write a background method to make app enter background(I call it in pictureInPictureControllerDidStartPictureInPicture callback), but it did not execute.

```
 private var player: AVPlayer?
    
    private var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer?
    
    private  var pipController : AVPictureInPictureController?
    
    private  var channel: FlutterMethodChannel
    
    private var flutterView: UIView?
    
    private var flutterWindow: UIWindow?

    
    public func background() {
        let targetSelect = #selector(NSXPCConnection.suspend)
        if UIApplication.shared.responds(to: targetSelect) {
            UIApplication.shared.perform(targetSelect)
        }
    }

   public func pictureInPictureControllerDidStartPictureInPicture(_ pictureInPictureController: AVPictureInPictureController) {
        background()
    }

 public func enterPiPMode(arguments: Any?,result: @escaping FlutterResult){
        dispose()
        if(isAvailable()){
            
            flutterWindow = windows()?.filter { window in
                          window.isKeyWindow
                      }.first
            
            flutterView = flutterWindow?.rootViewController?.view
            
            
            if let args = arguments as? [String: Any] {
                
                let iOSPlayUrl = args["iOSPlayUrl"] as? String ?? ""
                
                if(iOSPlayUrl.isEmpty){
                    print("PiPVideoPlugin error : iOSPlayUrl is Empty")
                    result(false)
                    return
                }
                do {
                    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
                    try audioSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, options:.mixWithOthers)
                    try audioSession.setActive(true)
                } catch {
                    print("PiPVideoPlugin error : AVAudioSession.sharedInstance")
                    result(false)
                    return
                }
                
                playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
                
                playerLayer!.frame = .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
                
                player = AVPlayer(playerItem: AVPlayerItem(url: URL(string: iOSPlayUrl)!))
                player!.isMuted = false
                player!.allowsExternalPlayback = true
                player!.accessibilityElementsHidden = true
                
                playerLayer!.player = player
                
                pipController = AVPictureInPictureController(playerLayer: playerLayer!)
                
                pipController!.delegate = self
                
                let enableControls = true
                
                pipController!.setValue(0, forKey: "controlsStyle")
                
                let enablePlayback = true
                pipController!.setValue(0, forKey: "requiresLinearPlayback")
                
                if #available(iOS 14.2, *) {
                    pipController!.canStartPictureInPictureAutomaticallyFromInline = true
                } else {
                    
                }
                
                player!.play()
                
       
                
                flutterView?.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer!)
                
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    
                    self.pipController!.startPictureInPicture()
                    
                    result(true)
                }

          
            }
            else {
                print("PiPVideoPlugin error : arguments error")
                result(false)
                return
            }
            
        }else{
            print("PiPVideoPlugin error : PiP is not available")
            result(false)
            return
        }
    }
```

The pip window automatically appears（App enter background automatically）

Comment: You can't move your app to the background. The user does this using the home button/home indicator.

Comment: "the pip window does not appear proactively" Can you show *any* app where it does?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it because the player is not ready
[video](https://imgur.com/m9JZQhh)